# LocaDate/LocalDateTime issue while using Generics

Tags: scala

I want to have method that would accept 2 arguments which are Comparable, compare and return result. This is the method:

```
def test[T <: Comparable[T]](a1: T, a2: T): Int = a1.compareTo(a2)
```

But there is an issue while using it with `LocalDate` as LocalDate is not comparable with other `LocalDate`, it's comparable with `ChronoLocalDate`. And when I try to call like this:

```
test(LocalDate.of(2017,1,2), LocalDate.of(2017, 2, 2))
```

I get error

```
type arguments [java.time.LocalDate] do not conform to method test's type parameter bounds [T <: Comparable[T]] test[LocalDate](a1, a2)
```

I understand the problem, but I don't understand how to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

```
def test[T <: Comparable[U], U >: T](a1: T, a2: T): Int = a1.compareTo(a2)
```

Then

```
test[LocalDate,  chrono.ChronoLocalDate](
  LocalDate.of(2017,1,2), 
  LocalDate.of(2017, 2, 2)
)
```

A shame you need the type parameters to be provided explicitly here

Comment: Yeah, I was hoping to get a solution which I shouldn't need to defined types explicitly

Comment: Better to use the typeclass approach you'd find in **scalaz**

Answer (score 0):

Say "`T` must be comparable with some supertype of `T`":

```
def test[T <: Comparable[_ >: T]](a1: T, a2: T): Int = a1.compareTo(a2)
```

Comment: Still get the error: 

`illegal cyclic reference involving type T
  def test[T <: Comparable[_ >: T]](a1: T, a2: T): Int = a1.compareTo(a2)`

Comment: Then you could try `def test[T](a1: T with Comparable[T], a2: T with Comparable[T])` or `def test[T](a1: T, a2: T)(implicit ord: Ordering[_ :> T])`.